# How To Report Records in Batchable Salesforce apex code such that it should report where the Level2 or Level3 are NULL

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

Here is my current Batchable apex code,currently this batch job  copies the data over from the new custom object ERT_Case_Type__c to the old custom object Case_Type__c

But problem is this job not copying when the Level2 or Level3 are not there. I mean say Level2 or Level3 is NULL

How can i make sure that Batchable Salesforce apex code  report the records which didn't got copied because there needs to be a matching set of L1, L2 and L3s in Case Type.

```
            global class ertcopybatch3pm implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
              
                global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
                    // collect the batches of records or objects to be passed to execute
                    
                    String query = 'select Case__c, Level_1__c, Level_2__c,Level_3__c  FROM ERT_Case_Type__c';
                    System.debug('ERT Case No is =====>' +query);
                    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
                }
                
                global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<ERT_Case_Type__c> exeList) {
                   
                    // process each batch of records
            List<Case_Type__c> listCTD = new List<Case_Type__c>();
                    System.debug('ERT Case No is =====>' +exeList);
                    for(ERT_Case_Type__c exe : exeList)
                    {        
                         listCTD.add(new Case_Type__c(Case__c=exe.Case__c,Level_1__c=exe.Level_1__c,Level_2__c=exe.Level_2__c,Level_3__c=exe.Level_3__c));
                       // System.debug('ERT Case No is =====>' +Case__c);
                    }
                    try {
                      System.debug('ERT Case No is =====>' +listCTD);
                        insert listCTD;
                    
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        System.debug(e);
                    }
                    
                }   
                
                global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
                  // execute any post-processing operations
              }
            }
```

Thanks in advance,
​​​​​​​Carolyn

Comment: Please [edit] to give the complete, verbatim text of the error and where it occurs.

Comment: @DavidReed  reprased the question what i need is How To Report Records in Batchable Salesforce apex code such that it should report where the  Level2 or Level3 are NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear right now why you're having an issue, or indeed what the issue is. There is no logic that is conditional on the values of the fields `Level_1__c`, `Level_2__c`, and `Level_3__c`, nor is there any possibility of a `NullPointerException` on any of these fields.

If the fields on the `Case_Type__c` object are required, or if there is a trigger or declarative automation on the `Case_Type__c` object that expects them to be non-`null`, you might be generating errors there. You do have a swallowed exception:

```
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.debug(e);
}
```

that you should remove, as it is hiding any real errors that occur upon `insert`. This may guide you to the real underlying problem.

Note additionally that you really do not need Batch Apex to do this operation. You could accomplish it much more easily using any Salesforce data loader to extract the one object and then load data into the other.

Batch Apex does not inherently report records that fail, particularly when you explicitly suppress exceptions. To do so, you'd need to use partial-success methods like `Database.insert()` to insert records, iterate over the results, and persist information about any failures to the database (possibly on the original source records). The code would be quite a bit more complex, but again, I really don't think you need to do this. You need to locate and fix the issue that is probably occurring on insert, and/or switch to using a data loader.